# Generic typemap that is applied to all named arguments except `this`

Tags: swig

Does anyone know if it is possible to make a generic typemap (ie without argument names) that applies to all arguments of this type except `this` pointers.

Something that goes like

```
%typemap(in, nothis=1) someClassObject* {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it is possible to do it by defining two typemaps:

```
%typemap(in) someClassObject * {
 // the nothis typemap
}

%typemap(in) someClassObject *self {
 // use the default typemap
}
```